# Default model binding throwing "No paramaterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form where we want to enter multiple deals for a single customer. The viewmodel for the form looks like this:

```
public class TradeSpendingEntryViewModel
{
    public TradeSpendingEntryViewModel()
    {
        Records = new List<TradeSpendingEntryViewModelRecord>();
    }

    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public SelectList PlanningYears { get; set; }

    public List<TradeSpendingEntryViewModelRecord> Records { get; set; }
}
```

We want to be able to add and remove record entry rows dynamically with javascript. Each record in the collection is:

```
public class TradeSpendingEntryViewModelRecord
{
    public TradeSpendingEntryViewModelRecord()
    {
    }

    public string LOB { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public SelectList AllowType { get; set; }
    public int Cases { get; set; }
    public bool EndCurrentDeal { get; set; }
    public Single DealRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to post data to my controller, I get an error indicating "No parameterless constructor defined for this object:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TradeSpendingEntryViewModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            return View(vm);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Stack trace indicates it happens during the model binding:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +183

My issue must be stemming from how I've setup my view, the markup of which I have based off this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<header class="clearfix">
        <img src="../../Content/images/logo.png" alt="Irving Consumer Products" />
        <h1>Enter Customer Deals</h1>
    </header>
    <hr />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer details</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date:
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" disabled="disabled" value="@DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Customer Number:
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerNumber, new { id = "customer-number" })
                    <a href="#" id="change-customer-number">Change me</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Customer Name:
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="customer-name" disabled="disabled" />
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Planning Year:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("PlanningYear", Model.PlanningYears)
                        <a href="#" id="change-planning-year">Change me</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <input type="button" value="Add line" id="add-line">
        <input type="button" value="Copy line" id="copy-line">
        <input type="button" value="Delete line" id="delete-line">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <table id="tradeSpendingEntry">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Line of business
                </th>
                <th>
                    Product Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Product Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Allowance
                    <br />
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cases
                </th>
                <th>
                    End Current Deal
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    End Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Rate
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var r in Model.Records)
        {
            <tbody data-entry-index="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="records[0].LOB" class="lobSelect" value="@r.LOB">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="records[0]ProductCodeSelected" value="@r.ProductCode" />-->
                    <input type="text" name="records[0].ProductCode" value="@r.ProductCode">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="product-description" disabled="disabled" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("records[0].AllowType", r.AllowType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="records[0].Cases" type="number" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="records[0].EndCurrentDeal">
                        <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
                        <option value="false">No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" name="records[0].StartDate" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" name="records[0].EndDate" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="records[0].DealRate" />
                </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Comments:
                </td>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <input type="text" class="comment" name="records[0].Comments" />
                </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
        }
    </table>

    <footer>
        <div class="buttonGroup">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes">
        <input type="button" value="Main Menu">
        <input type="button" value="View Customer Deals">
    </div>
    </footer>
    }
```

So, my hope was that the fields in the first fieldset would map to the immediate properties of the TradeSpendingEntryViewModel object (CustomerName, Date, PlanningYears). Then, for each  representing a TradeSpendingEntryViewModelRecord would be bound as an item in the TradeSpendingEntryViewModel.Records collection. Instead, I just get a mysterious "No parameterless constructor defined" exception, despite both the ViewModel and the record object both having paramaterless constructors.

My question is, can I use the default model binder using the conventions indicated in the aforementioned article, or do I need to build a custom model binder for this purpose?

For completeness sake, the following is the markup of the form that gets generated after a user dynamically adds a line to the form via javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="/TradeSpendingEntry/Index">
<header class="clearfix">
<img alt="Irving Consumer Products" src="../../Content/images/logo.png">
<h1>Enter Customer Deals</h1>
</header>
<hr>
<fieldset>
<legend>Customer details</legend>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th> Date: </th>
<td>
<input id="dp1363608756704" class="hasDatepicker" type="date" value="18/03/2013" disabled="disabled" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> Customer Number: </th>
<td>
<input id="customer-number" type="text" value="" name="CustomerNumber">
<a id="change-customer-number" href="#">Change me</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> Customer Name: </th>
<td>
<input id="customer-name" type="text" disabled="disabled" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> Planning Year: </th>
<td>
<select id="PlanningYears" name="PlanningYears">
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
<a id="change-planning-year" href="#">Change me</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
<div class="buttonGroup">
<input id="add-line" type="button" value="Add line">
<input id="copy-line" type="button" value="Copy line">
<input id="delete-line" type="button" value="Delete line">
</div>
<hr>
<table id="tradeSpendingEntry">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> </th>
<th> Line of business </th>
<th> Product Code </th>
<th> Product Description </th>
<th>
Allowance
<br>
Type
</th>
<th> Cases </th>
<th> End Current Deal </th>
<th> Start Date </th>
<th> End Date </th>
<th> Rate </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-entry-index="0">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox">
</td>
<td>
<input class="lobSelect" type="text" name="records[0].LOB">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="records[0].ProductCode">
</td>
<td>
<input class="product-description" type="text" disabled="disabled" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
</td>
<td>
<select id="records_0__AllowType" name="records[0].AllowType">
<option selected="selected">BillBack$</option>
<option>Billback%</option>
<option>O&A%</option>
<option>Coop%</option>
<option>VR%</option>
<option>Lump - O&A$</option>
<option>Lump - CP$</option>
<option>Lump - VR$</option>
<option>Lump - BB$</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="records[0].Cases">
</td>
<td>
<select name="records[0].EndCurrentDeal">
<option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input id="dp1363608756707" class="hasDatepicker" type="date" name="records[0].StartDate">
</td>
<td>
<input id="dp1363608756708" class="hasDatepicker" type="date" name="records[0].EndDate">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="records[0].DealRate">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td> Comments: </td>
<td colspan="8">
<input class="comment" type="text" name="records[0].Comments">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody data-entry-index="1">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox">
</td>
<td>
<input class="lobSelect" type="text" name="records[1].LOB">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="records[1].ProductCode">
</td>
<td>
<input class="product-description" type="text" disabled="disabled" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
</td>
<td>
<select id="records_0__AllowType" name="records[1].AllowType">
<option selected="selected">BillBack$</option>
<option>Billback%</option>
<option>O&A%</option>
<option>Coop%</option>
<option>VR%</option>
<option>Lump - O&A$</option>
<option>Lump - CP$</option>
<option>Lump - VR$</option>
<option>Lump - BB$</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="records[1].Cases">
</td>
<td>
<select name="records[1].EndCurrentDeal">
<option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input id="dp1363608756709" class="hasDatepicker" type="date" name="records[1].StartDate">
</td>
<td>
<input id="dp1363608756710" class="hasDatepicker" type="date" name="records[1].EndDate">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="records[1].DealRate">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td> Comments: </td>
<td colspan="8">
<input class="comment" type="text" name="records[1].Comments">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<footer>
<div class="buttonGroup">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Changes">
<input type="button" value="Main Menu">
<input type="button" value="View Customer Deals">
</div>
</footer>
</form>
```

Comment: Pretty much all your fields use lower case `r`, but your Model uses upper case `R`. They **must** match.

Comment: Changed: TradeSpendingEntryViewModel.Records -> TradeSpendingEntryViewModel.records ... still getting "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: From your ViewModels I can tell that they have only `SelectList` type properties, which doesn't have parameterless constructor. Have you tried to remove them? Also your document is not valid. I found 2 `select`s with id='records_0__AllowType'.

Comment: You're right, the SelectList was the sticky widget, couldn't for the life of me figure out what the heck was going on

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without a doubt it is the `SelectList`. I had the same problem just yesterday.

If you look at the SelectList all of it's constructors require a parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx

The problem is when your `Action` is called `public ActionResult Index(TradeSpendingEntryViewModel vm)`

The controller tries to bind the data sent back on `POST` to `TradeSpendingEntryViewModel` upon which it needs to set the value for `PlanningYears` which it tires to do by creating a new `SelectList`

To fix the problem, you either need to make the SelectList a private variable aka a backing field, and then set it to an empty list by default. This gives it the parameterized constructor it needs:

```
    //select list
    private SelectList planningYears = new SelectList(new List<YourObject>());

    public SelectList PlanningYears 
    {
        get
        {
            return planningYears;
        }
        set
        {
            locations = planningYears;
        }
    }
```

Or change PlanningYears to a List<> and convert it to a select list on the view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlanningYears , new SelectList(Model.PlanningYears ), "choose", null)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much, you've saved me tons of time here.

Comment: what is `locations` in the setter?

Answer (score 0):

this will resolve your selectlist issue.
create new class with name `SelectListNew` and inherit it from `SelectList` as mention below example. now instead of `SelectList` use `SelectListNew`

```
public class SelectListNew : SelectList
{
    public SelectListNew() : base(string.Empty) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items) : base(items) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, object selectedValue) : base(items, selectedValue) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, object selectedValue, IEnumerable disabledValues) : base(items, selectedValue, disabledValues) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValue) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, string dataGroupField, object selectedValue) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, dataGroupField, selectedValue) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue, IEnumerable disabledValues) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValue, disabledValues) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, string dataGroupField, object selectedValue, IEnumerable disabledValues) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, dataGroupField, selectedValue, disabledValues) { }
    public SelectListNew(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, string dataGroupField, object selectedValue, IEnumerable disabledValues, IEnumerable disabledGroups) : base(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, dataGroupField, selectedValue, disabledValues, disabledGroups) { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a better idea! Simple declare your property (selectList) as method:

do the following

```
//fill it if whatever you want from db
private List<YourList> happyList = new List<YourList>(); 

//that way mvc will never try to instantiate selectList on Action execution
public SelectList PlanningYears() 
    {
        return new SelectList(happyList,"happyID","happyDesc","");
    }
```

a lot of time doing properties in c# made me forget how simple it was....